# "Like" system PHP, using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i want to make like/unlike system with PHP and jQuery/AJAX..

Here is my form in PHP `foreach`... Here i have own id's for every form;

```
<?php foreach ($vid as $var) { ?>

<form class="classform" action="functions/videolike.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $var['video_id'];?>">
    <button class="submitbuttonclass"type="submit">Like</button>
</form> 
<?php } ?>
```

Here is my Ajax script;

```
<script>
// this is the id of the submit button
$(".submitbuttonclass").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
         type: 'post',
         url: "functions/videolike.php",
         data: $(".classform").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
         success: function(data)
         {
             alert(data); // show response from the php script.
         }
    });
    return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
</script>
```

1. the codes are working but not correctly;
2. When i click "like" button is working good, i cheked the database, caunting,  inserting, deleting , working good...
3. But I want to make this with AJAX becouse, refreshing page is stopping the video when user watching video if he click the like button. Video is preloading becouse page refresh...
4. After i add my ajax script its working. But when i am clicking the like button, AJAX is posting to PHP, only the last id in the foreach loop,

THE Question?
How to make AJAX to get all of the id's in PHP foreach loop ??

And this is my **videolike.php** if you want to check;

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_POST['id'] && @$_SESSION["userid"]){

    require_once "connectdb.php";
    $id = $_POST["id"];


$VLcheck = "SELECT count(*) FROM `videolikes` WHERE user_id = ? AND liked_vid_id=?"; 
$reslike = $conn->prepare($VLcheck); 
$reslike->execute(array($_SESSION["userid"],$id));
$VLrow = $reslike->fetchColumn();
echo $VLrow;
if ($VLrow > 0){
    $VLcheck = "DELETE FROM `videolikes` WHERE user_id = ? AND liked_vid_id=?"; 
    $reslike = $conn->prepare($VLcheck); 
    $reslike->execute(array($_SESSION["userid"],$id));

} else {
    $curentsess= $_SESSION["userid"];
    $INSlike = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO videolikes(user_id, liked_vid_id)
        VALUES('$curentsess','$id')");
    $INSlike->execute();


}} else {die;}  
?>
```

Comment: Try stopping browser default execution by changing the `.click` listener and start of function to this: `$('.classform').on('click', 'button.submitbuttonclass', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); [... rest of function] });` (Also use `$(this).serialize()` instead of `$('.class').serialize()`) I think you missed stopping the default execution, so the results you're getting server-side are not those from your `$.ajax()` function. Also, you mention a php foreach() loop. However, none present in your example.

Answer (score 1):

As you have a lot forms with class `.classform`, so how do you think your script should select the proper one?

The asnwer is - script can't, you should help it). Use `.closest` function to find closest `<form>` for a clicked button:

```
$(".submitbuttonclass").click(function() {
    var form = $(this).closest("form");
    // or find closest element with class `classform`
    //var form = $(this).closest(".classform");

    $.ajax({
         type: 'post',
         url: "functions/videolike.php",
         data: form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
         success: function(data)
         {
             alert(data); // show response from the php script.
         }
    });
    return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
```

Comment: I tryed it... When i click **LIKE** button just targeting me to functions/videolike.php.. How to stop this targeting

Comment: I suppose you have javascript errors. Check what's wrong in developers console.

Comment: In  the console i dont have any javascript errors.. After i change my script with your, Your script is working but targeting me to videolike.php, i want to make without any page refresh...

Comment: Works fine, alerting the result, and no targeting to videolike.php, but the only mistake is: AJAX sends to PHP only the last id in foreach loop... But when i click inspect element in browser, i see every form input value have a own unique id...  After i add your script, its no alerting the result and redirecting me to videolike.php...

Comment: look i am using only this source: <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: I still suppose there's some error in a script. I can't produce your conditions, but advise you to debug your click function line by line.

Comment: Created a similar fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/rLnL6c8j/ As you can see clicking on `like` alerts proper data.

Comment: Dude Yes your code is worked now this is my bad.. :D thank you verry much

Comment: why dude ? xxxxx

Comment: Btw if my answer solves your problem - you can accept it and, optionally, upvote.